# Is it possible to change the size of a foreignObject after it is created?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

is it possible to change the size of a `foreignObject` (`<textarea>`) after it is created/added? Or do I need to remove it and add a new one with the needed size? 
I tried `.attr("width", x)` and `.style("width", x)` but no change at all. Is there some kind of trick or is it simply not possible? 
Tested under newest chrome.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change the textarea size, and `style("width", x)` does work. However, it has to be `"100px"` instead of `100`, for instance.

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var foreign = svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 20);

var textarea = foreign.append("xhtml:textarea")
  .style("width", "40px")
  .style("height", "40px")
  .style("background-color", "wheat")
  .html("This is a textarea inside a foreign object");

textarea.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .style("width", "200px")
  .style("height", "100px")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

You can also use `"rows"` and `"cols"`, but the result is not nice:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var foreign = svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 20);

var textarea = foreign.append("xhtml:textarea")
  .attr("rows", 5)
  .attr("cols", 5)
  .style("background-color", "wheat")
  .html("This is a textarea inside a foreign object");

textarea.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .attr("rows", 8)
  .attr("cols", 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: OOh my god, thank you. The "px" is the trick. Didn't thought of that. Thank you very much Gerardo.